# What is the optimal way to find common nodes in two BST

Tags: data-structures, binary-search-tree

I am looking for the most optimal in terms of complexity(space and time).

My approach until now is:
Traverse one tree in-order and for each nodeId, search that nodeId in second tree.

Node structure:

```
struct node{
    long long nodeId;
    node *left;
    node *right;
};
```

Please let me know if any doubts about the question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming one tree is `n` long and the other is `m` long, your approach is `O(n*m)` long, while you could do it in `O(n+m)`.

Let us say you have to pointers to where you are in each tree (`location_1` and `location_2`). Start going through both trees at the same time, and each time decide which pointer you want to advance. Lets say `location_1` is pointing at a node with `nodeId = 4` and `location_2` is at `nodeId = 7`. In this case `location_1` moves forwards since any node before the one it is looking at has a smaller value then 4.

By "moves forwards" I mean an in-order traverse of the tree.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a standard merge in O(n+m) time. The general algorithm is:

```
n1 = Tree1.Root
n2 = Tree2.Root
while (n1 != NULL && n2 != NULL)
{
    if (n1.Value == n2.Value)
    {
        // node exists in both trees. Advance to next node.
        n1 = GetInorderSuccessor(n1)
        n2 = GetInorderSuccessor(n2)
    }
    else if (n1.Value > n2.Value)
    {
        // n2 is not in Tree1
        n2 = GetInorderSuccessor(n2)
    }
    else
    {
        // n1 is smaller than n2
        // n1 is not in Tree2
        n1 = GetInorderSuccessor(n1)
    }
}
// At this point, you're at the end of one of the trees
// The other tree has nodes that are not in the other.
while (n1 != NULL)
{
    // n1 is not in Tree2. Output it.
    // and then get the next node.
    n1 = GetInorderSuccessor(n1)
}
while (n2 != NULL)
{
    // n2 is not in Tree1. Output it.
    // and then get the next node.
    n2 = GetInorderSuccessor(n2)
}
```

The only hard part here is that `GetInorderSuccessor` call. If you're doing this with a tree, then you'll need to maintain state through successive calls to that function. You can't depend on a standard recursive tree traversal to do it for you. Basically, you need a tree iterator.

The other options is to first traverse each tree to make a list of the nodes in order, and then write the merge to work work with those lists.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly modified Morris Traversal should solve the solution with movement similar to merge part of merge sort. Time Complexity: O(m + n), Space Complexity: O(1).